# What is a lower convex hull? (Of a finite number of points in the plane)

Tags: galois-theory, convex-hulls

I am trying to understand Newton Polygons for computing Galois Groups and they are defined as a lower convex hull (see the third page of http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/Coleman_GaloisNewton.pdf). However I couldn't find a definition online. Does anyone know what a lower convex hull is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very roughly (and thus a comment rather than an answer), it's defined by the minimal (sub)set of your set of points such that any line between two of your points is 'above' the lines between (adjacent) members of the subset. Slightly less roughly, it's the 'lower envelope' of all line segments between any two points in the set; the set of segments such that no other segment is ever below them (has smaller y-coordinate).

Comment: Thus, e.g. the lower convex hull of the points $\langle 0, 4\rangle, \langle 1, 0\rangle, \langle 2,2\rangle, \langle 3,0\rangle, \langle 4,4\rangle$ would the segments between consecutive points of $\langle 0, 4\rangle, \langle 1,0\rangle, \langle 3,0\rangle,$ and $\langle 4,4\rangle$ ; the point at $\langle 2,2\rangle$ is 'above' this envelope.

Comment: (Often it's specifically defined to be the set of all points in the plane above these segments, or something similar, but those are just minor tweaks. It's a good exercise to show that the collection of 'lower-minimal' segments _does_ form a chain, and that it can be ordered by nondecreasing $x$ coordinate.)

Comment: One way of defining this is to erect at each point $(n, v(a_n))$ the infinite vertical half-line going up from the point. Then take the convex hull of the union of these. There will be vertical sides to this polygon, and they have some minor significance, too. But mostly you want just the nonvertical sides of the convex polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your help Steven, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Lubin, but won't the convex hull of the infinite half-lines just be area above the "line" formed by connecting the dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, you take a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which you imagine as a set of pins. Then you tie a string to the leftmost point and wrap it tightly around the bottom of the set of pins.

Formally, consider all of the half-planes $H_u = \{v : \langle u, v \rangle \ge c\}$ with $u$ in the upper half-plane $\{u = (x, y) : y \ge 0\}$. The lower convex hull is the intersection of all these half-planes which contain your set of points. I like to call these "lower inequalities" because I picture them as lines which are below all of the points.

In the context of such Newton polygons, it is unimportant whether you are considering this as a convex set or considering just the bounded faces of that convex set.

Convex hull:

[image: Convex Hull]

Lower convex hull:

[image: Lower Convex Hull]